# I was awarded chat privialages but can't chat?

Tags: support, chat

Why can I not chat after getting chat privileges?
Does getting suspended from physic se prevent me from chatting here?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, your suspension on Physics included a network-wide suspension from chat for 270 days.

Comment: just to clarify is it just Physics? or any SE Suspension because the user does have another suspension that ends in March of next year and that's (by rough numbers) is 309 days away?

Comment: @Memor-X It was Physics in this case, yes.